# What means of {*} in dict syntax in tcl

Tags: dictionary, tcl

In tcl, there are some code idioms I am not familiar with, what {*} means in dict creat?

```
namespace eval ::resistorColor {
    variable colors [dict create {*}{
        black   0
        brown   1
        red     2
        orange  3
        yellow  4
        green   5
        blue    6
        violet  7
        grey    8
        white   9
    }]
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not an idiom, it's one of the basic rules of Tcl syntax: https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/Tcl.html#M9 .

It's being used here because the key/value pairs for the dict have been written as a list enclosed in `{}`, this allows them to be written on separate lines.  But the `dict create` command doesn't want a single list, it wants the keys and values passed as separate arguments.  So `{*}` is being used to split that list apart into the separate arguments for the `dict` command.

An alternative to this would be to use backslashes to continue the list of arguments for dict on multiple lines:

```
variable colors [dict create \
    black   0 \
    brown   1 \
    red     2 \
    ...etc...
```

Comment: One of the absolute foundational principles of the design of the `dict` command is that keys can be arbitrary, which in turn drives a lot of how the API is done; keys are never parsed for structure as you have no idea what might be in there.

Answer (score 2):

A well-formed list can also be used as a dictionary:

```
% set colors {
    black   0
    brown   1
    red     2
    orange  3
    yellow  4
    green   5
    blue    6
    violet  7
    grey    8
    white   9
}

% dict get $colors violet
7
```

I like to use the `dict` (and `list`) commands when constructing things to make the intent of the code quite obvious: "I will use this as a dict"